# Safari Displays iPhone version of Google

Tags: safari, user-agent

If you look at the image below, you'll see that I'm getting the iPhone version of Google on my Mac. If I refresh, it stays the same, but curiously enough, if I visit https://www.google.com (note SSL), it looks fine. If I do a search, it first takes me to the iPhone results, then upon refresh, it displays the normal results.

Things I have tried:

- Checked Useragent (this may actually be part of the problem... I had switched to iPhone useragent for something and then switched back, but I had visited Google in between)
- Deleted cookies
- Deleted com.apple.Safari.plist

[image: picture]

Comment: What happens if you hit that Classic link down there?

Comment: It becomes normal... but when I come back, it's back to mobile.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you visit a different Google, say, http://google.co.uk ?

Comment: No, it seems to be limited to google.com

Comment: I put another thing to try in my answer. Maybe it will help?

Comment: What happens if you create a new user on your machine, login to that, open Safari, and navigate to Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try emptying your cache.

I reproduced your problem by changing my user-agent to "Mobile Safari".  Even after changing it back and restarting Safari, it still showed the mobile version.

I tried using "Reset Safari" and just flagging "Delete cookies", but that did not work.

However, when I used "Empty Cache", Google started working properly again.

I did this a few more times just to confirm that it was "Empty Cache" that was fixing the problem.  I don't know *why* this works, though.

Comment: One would think that reset safari already does that! Apparently not... strange. Congrats! +1

Answer (score 0):

What does [this page](http://andylangton.co.uk/online-tools/check-browser-headers) say about user-agent and accepted media types?

Your problem seems to be in the headers Safari sends, since the normal page is restored after one visit. I suspect Safari is accepting a wap mime type (text/vnd.wap.wml, application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml).

Comment: Accepted media types: `application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5`

Comment: Same as I have. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Safari are you using? if changing the user agent back to normal doesn't fix anything, maybe reinstalling Safari would help.